# Do-while loop reapeats as the value of the variable changes

Tags: c, char

So I am trying to create a program to tell me what number i am thinking between 0 and 126. I wrote a small program in C which asks you what number you are thinking and if it is smaller than the one i say a calculate the new number bassed on the upper and inferior limit i have set. But when i put an answer like - or + i get a strange bug where the line which should be displayed 1 time is written 2 times and if i put as an answer -- i get 3 lines writen which is strange. What am i missing here?

```c
    int valoreSup=126;
    char risposta;
    int valoreInf=0;
    int N = (valoreInf+valoreSup)/2;

    do
    {
        printf("E il tuo valore: %d\n", N);
        scanf("%c", &risposta);
        if (risposta=='-') {
            valoreSup=N;
            int N = (valoreInf+valoreSup)/2;
        }
        if (risposta=='+') {
            valoreInf=N;
            int N = (valoreInf+valoreSup)/2;
        }
    } while(risposta!='=');

    printf("%d\n", N);
```

There are no error messages(I am using atom), but the results are strange. tha value of N does not change and the loop repeats in a strange way.

Comment: Change "int N" to "N" in your `if` blocks -- otherwise you have multiple variables called "N" and never change the first of them.

Comment: the same things happens only in this case the response is the same as the number of char i put.

Comment: @Dmitri yes that solved it. I am suck an idiot, what a mistake

Answer (score 1):

You keep re-declaring variable `N`, which results in variables named `N` that are specific to the scope of the bodies of your if statements. Keep only the first declaration, before the do-while loop, and remove the other two, like this:

```
int N = (valoreInf+valoreSup)/2;
do
{
    printf("E il tuo valore: %d\n", N);
    scanf(" %c", &risposta);
    if (risposta=='-') {
        valoreSup=N;
        N = (valoreInf+valoreSup)/2;
    }
    if (risposta=='+') {
        valoreInf=N;
        N = (valoreInf+valoreSup)/2;
    }
} while(risposta!='=');
```

because what you want is to assign a new value to the outer `N`, not introduce another, different and new, variable.

Moreover, as you probably saw already, [I left a space before `%c` in `scanf()`](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/), because if you iterate over this loop, you'll read the newline character that you pressed when you were inputing your value for `risposta`.